# Getting the website fill-in form data to spreadsheat or database

Tags: database, html, forms, css

I'm facing a rather logistic problem and would need suggestions on which way should we go.

Since our hosting provider doesn't allow mysql bases, we had to put a HTML5/CSS3/Bootstrap website (instead of wordpress).

What we would need now is creating a page where we would allow our visitors to fill-in certain forms. For the sake of argument, let's say this page would allow three different fill-in forms with fields like Name, contact info, etc.

My question would be how could we automate the process where the information from those forms goes directly to a database or some sort of a spreadsheet, so we could easily look the data without having to manually insert it?
Is that even possible? What technology should we use, which way should we go?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databases are file based. So at the end of the day a mySQL database is nothing else, than a file somewhere in your file tree. So, you could use PHP to create a .csv (or .txt whatever) file and keep your data there directly, avoiding the need of a DBMS.

The [filesystem methods](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php) built in PHP are very useful for your endeavour. Especially [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), [fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) and [fclose](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php).

```
<?php
   $fp = fopen('data.txt', 'a'); //append, instead of override
   fwrite($fp, 'formData');
   fclose($fp);
?>
```

?>

Of course this solution only works, if your hoster allows PHP.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will definetly look into it, don't know about PHP but will check it out. Thanks!